# What is SourceId in requests to SharePoint Search API?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-search, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to implement people searching with SharePoint REST API in JS and I've found that it can be done by directly providing `SourceId` in the request body. So currently my request the next way:

```js
function searchEmployees(value) {
  fetchData(
    `${appWebUrl}/_api/search/postquery`, // App URL
    accessTokens.sharepoint, // Authorization: "Bearer ..."
    'POST', // method
    // Body
    { 
      'request': {
        'Querytext': `${value}`,
        'RowLimit': 30,
        'SourceId': 'b09a7990-05ea-4af9-81ef-edfab16c4e31'
      }
    }
  ).then(renderData);
}
```

But this `SourceId` was found in the random internet source, not the official documentation. So basically the questions are next:

- What is `SourceId`?
- What are possible values of `SourceId`?
- Is there any good documentation on `SourceId`s?
- Is there any good documentation on working with SharePoint for searching people?
- Is there a better way of searching people? (If there is, why is it better?)

Answer (score 1):

The SourceId is the result sources you defined.

[image]